# Getting values from python DataFrame based on mapping array values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to loop on a dataframe and array of values which have addresses , I need to find in the dataframe where the rows with the equal address and get back the longtitude and latitude for that address , I already did the searching part , but how can I get the latitude and longtitude values.

```
df_ll = DataFrame (hotels_ll,columns=['Address','City','long','lat']) 
            for xrf in array_of_hotels:
                np.where((df_ll['Address'] == xrf[0]),array_of_coordinates.append({
                        "long":df_ll['long'],
                        "lat":df_ll['lat'][0]}),'Nan')
```

Comment: Please try to write in short sentences - it's hard to understand what you mean. And check the formatting of your code block.

Comment: @icemtel I edited my question ,please tell me if you need more clarification